# when implementing ErrorProtocol, keep getting error 1) use of undeclared type ErrorProtocol 2) type does not conform to protocol RawRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, exception

I'm learning swift by following the swift programming lanuguage 3.0 handbook. In the error handling chapter, when one want to declare an error type, you implement the `ErrorProtocol` protocol. As shown below:

```
enum VendingMachineError: ErrorProtocol{
    case invalidSelection
    case insufficientFuns(coinsNeeded: Int)
    case outOfStock
}
```

But in xcode playground, I keep getting the error message

1) use of undeclared type ErrorProtocol

2) type VendingMachineError does not conform to protocol RawRepresentable

Why is this happening? I'm simply coping the code from the book.

[image]

Comment: `enum VendingMachineError: Error {`

Answer (score 1):

It's not `ErrorProtocol`, it's `ErrorType`, you declare that when creating error enum

Comment: OP it is not using Swift 2, he is using Swift 3 should be `Error`

Comment: Thank you all so much for the helpful comments! its puzzling that in the book swift programming language 3.0, it says we should use ErrorProtocol, even though we are suppose to use Error in swift 3. Thanks again for the help!